# Linux rename files based on another file in the directory?

Tags: linux, bash, batch-rename

I've got about 750 directories that contain two files each:

```
long_somewhat_random_filename.jpg
thumb.jpg
```

What I'd like to do is use `find` or something similar to rename `thumb.jpg` to `long_somewhat_random_filename_thumb.jpg`. My brain's kinda fuzzy at the moment.

I could do it with a perl script, but if there's a somewhat easy way to do it in bash, that's easier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give the script below a shot. Right now the `echo` makes it benign so you can *try before you buy* so to speak.  If you like what you see, remove the `echo` and run the script again to actually make the changes.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read file; do
 echo mv "${file%/*}/thumb.jpg" "${file%.*}_thumb.jpg"
done < <(find . -type f ! -name "thumb.jpg" -name "*.jpg")
```

#### Input

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.jpg"
./dir1/dir1_foo_bar.jpg
./dir1/thumb.jpg
./dir2/dir2_foo_bar.jpg
./dir2/thumb.jpg
./dir3/dir3_foo_bar.jpg
./dir3/thumb.jpg
./dir4/dir4_foo_bar.jpg
./dir4/thumb.jpg
./dir5/dir5_foo_bar.jpg
./dir5/thumb.jpg
```

#### Output

```
$ ./mvthumb.sh
mv ./dir1/thumb.jpg ./dir1/dir1_foo_bar_thumb.jpg
mv ./dir2/thumb.jpg ./dir2/dir2_foo_bar_thumb.jpg
mv ./dir3/thumb.jpg ./dir3/dir3_foo_bar_thumb.jpg
mv ./dir4/thumb.jpg ./dir4/dir4_foo_bar_thumb.jpg
mv ./dir5/thumb.jpg ./dir5/dir5_foo_bar_thumb.jpg
```